# misunderstanding on django html, css, view functions

Tags: css, django

I'm new on django development. I had created any html files and now I want to integrate on django. The problem is that I can't achieve it.

If I type the following on urls.py I can see css but I can't run the function on views.py that I need to save data on database or for example to check fields on web.

```
(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'templates/', 'show_indexes': True})
```

I had set all my html, css and images on templates folder.

Do you understand what I am trying to explain?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, sorry. Are you trying to serve static HTML files directly, without views?

Comment: You might want to try the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/). It'll make things clearer.

Comment: Yes, I need to server HTML files previously created but I need to create some functions in views that checks the page fields.

If I type this in url.py:

 url(r'^buttons', buttons_page)

and the in views.py this:

def buttons_page(request):   
   actions....

If I do as this way I can't get css files. Just doing:

(r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',  {'document_root': 'templates/', 'show_indexes': True})

is the only way to get css files but I can't check field

Comment: It sounds like you want to browse your html, css and image file in a web browser by using Django's framework, is that correct?  Web frameworks exist to separate templates, static and media files.

Answer (score 2):

You should really have a look at the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/), but essentially you need to route you urls to the views.py functions.

This is an example from the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^articles/2003/$', 'news.views.special_case_2003'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/$', 'news.views.year_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/$', 'news.views.month_archive'),
    (r'^articles/(\d{4})/(\d{2})/(\d+)/$', 'news.views.article_detail'),
)
```

Here you can see that the different urls are routed to the different functions in a views.py file.

So you need to create a url config for each different url, and then you will be able to handle it with a view function.

Comment: I know, but how can I get css in your mode?

Comment: Read the documentation about staticfiles